# Disable ADB over wifi but leave connection over USB functioning

Tags: android, adb, wifi

I have device with android installed that needs to be available in company network. Device is Khadas Vim3 single board computer and is fully rooted.

ADB connection over wifi is enabled by default.

Command `adb usb` will disable connection over wifi, but after device reboot its enabled again and anyone who knows IP address can connect to it. I want to disable disable connection over wifi permamently. It needs to be turned off when device is rebooted. Only connection over usb should be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Khadas Vim3 have info about adb tcp port stored in file /vendor/build.prop.

To edit this file first remount /vendor directory writable.
`mount -o rw,remount /vendor`

Then edit build.prop file `vi /vendor/build.prop` and change value for option
service.adb.tcp.port to -1. Former value is 5555

New value: `service.adb.tcp.port=-1`

Then remount /vendor as read only `mount -o ro,remount /vendor`

And reboot device.

After that adb no longer connects to device through wifi but can connect through usb.